# pyspark to_date convert returning null for invalid dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, date, pyspark

I am trying to convert a string column to date using to_date. Everything is working fine, however, my requirement is to fail the spark job if there is any bad data, that is, any malformed input for date. Currently, to_date is returning null, but not falling. How to make sure that job will be failed in such scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the `to_date` function is dependent on the `spark.sql.ansi.enabled` Spark option.
When it is disabled (the default), Spark uses a Hive compliant dialect and returns null results instead of failing.
Conversely, if enabled, Spark will be ANSI compliant and will fail if the input is malformed as [stated here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html#functions-with-different-behaviors).

That said, you may not want to enable `spark.sql.ansi.enabled` because it has many other effects, see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html).

An alternative solution is to use an UDF instead of the `to_date` function to perform the date parsing, and throw an exception if the parse fails.